# App Engine SDK stop logging things randomly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been working on an app for a while but lately my python SDK decided that it would log things up to a certain point then display nothing anymore.

The only way to change its mind it is to stop and start the app again and it blocks at the same point (which is hard to debug)

The last thing that I see is

```
GET /_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=SOMERANDOMID with an answer 200
```

The app works fine, I can do calls to Cloud Endpoint, get my results, etc... Just the Logging display is gone.

For some reason when I upload my app, everything works fine, the logs works fine.

Anything that I can do like cleaning some cache somewhere, I don't know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. It was due to some wsgi middleware setup that I had to manage sessions